# Replace anchor tag with span tag

Tags: wordpress, drop-down-menu

I have created my custom menu having many items and sub items, the markup is like this `<a href="#">Item</a>`but for parent element I need to replace anchor tag with the span tag having some class for styling purpose, only for my parent elements. It should be like this, `<span class="my-class">Parent Element</span>`. Can any one please guide me?

Answer (score 0):

you can control your css by applying certain css to the menu as below:

```
<?php 
  wp_nav_menu( array('theme_location' => 'header-menu' ,'container_class'=> 'header')); ?>
```